# how to include a partial .erb in a liquid template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, liquid

I'm trying to someting like this

```
{% for movie in movies%}
*{{ movie.name }}* {{ movie.price | currency }}
Ratin: {{ movie.rating }}
{% endfor %}

{% render_erb 'partial/footer' %}
```

footer would be a file like footer.erb.html.

How can I include as a partial as a erb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is very easy:

```
{% template 'common/footer' %}
```

Comment: where is the template documentation in liquid?

Answer (score 0):

when you call render, the file extension is used to chose which template engine to use. So a regular call to `render` *should* do the trick, given that your partial has the right extension. I say *should* because I didn't try, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: do you mind that, the following should work? {{ render :partial => 'footer' }}

Comment: I think it should, yes. But I don't know the `liquid` engine so I might miss something here